# How to use Spring Data JPA Repository to query from 2 tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I have 2 tables say Student and Teacher and say Student has a Many-To-One relationship to Teacher and say, teacherId serves as the foreign key.

How can I use spring data JPA repo methods, in a way - `findByTeacherName`, if I want to query something like below,

```
select * from Student S, Teacher T 
    where T.teacherName = 'SACHIN' and S.teacherId = T.teacherId
```

Note : Here I wanna query using only `StudentRepository`, which is created using `StudentHibernateMapping` class that has a relationship to `TeacherHibernateMapping` class

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 61):

There will be a repository method on StudentRepository

```
List<Student> findByTeacher_TeacherId(String teacherId);
```

your entityClass should be like..

```
@Entity
Class Student {
  @Id
  String studentId;
  @ManyToOne
  private Teacher teacher;
}
```

and Teacher Class would be..

```
@Entity
Class Teacher {
  @Id
  private String teacherId;
}
```

Here the key thing you need to know is:

findBy + (the foreign key member of student class **with first letter Upper**) + underscore +the data member of Teacher Class **with first letter UpperCase** +(String teacherId);

this will give you a list of students belonging to that teacher

Comment: Good solution. I wonder if this approach is documented somewhere. I couldn't find any so far.

Comment: Hi @LiangZhou Here you go..  
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation  
we don't even need to add `underscore` in method as well ..  
for example :  
    `List<Student> findByTeacherTeacherId(String teacherId);`  
This will also work.

Answer (score 8):

Regarding @prateek-singh's entities, it should also be possible to define the query without id at all, simply by the foreign entity.

`List<Student> findByTeacher(Teacher teacher);`

Comment: This also works for me , along with one provided by Prateek Singh.

Answer (score 3):

There are an ample of ways to do that, read up on the convention of [method naming](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) that explains the use of nested properties, or for more complex queries use [@Query annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).

Comment: Thanks @zoran. In particular, i just want to understand whether something like combining 2 tables in the where clause equivalent,like, `findByTeacherIdAndStudentId` is supported. I however know it works with NativeSQl.